# Connection between two computers using sockets in C. (TCP)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtXEMwSG5-8&t=387s&ab_channel=EduonixLearningSolutions) tutorial to learn something about socket programming in C. Everythink is working just fine, but it only works on one PC. I would like to know how to host server on one PC (I will use rpi4 in future) and connect to the server with client on another PC.

This is code for server, when client connect to server, it sends "You have reached the server" message to client.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char server_message[256] = "You have reached the server";
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket, 0);

    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

    send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

here is client.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int network_socket = 0;
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    
    if (connection_status == -1)
    {
        printf("Connection Error!");
        return 0;
    }

    char server_response[256];
    recv(network_socket, server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

    printf("Data from server %s\n", server_response);

    close(network_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

I naively tried to replace INADDR_ANY with inet_addr("myip"); but it doesnt work.

Thanks for any help!
(Also sorry my first post on sof, hope everything is ok)

Comment: Use this as you tutorial: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/.  Take note of how the client (simple stream client) and server (simple stream server) are coded.  You are misusing most the the API's.

Comment: @thurizas Thanks. I dont know how Im misusing most of the APIs since I just followed the tutorial. I will definitely check it. Will I find there answer for my question ?

Comment: You MUST correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls like send, recv.  You MUST NOT feed char arrays that are not NUL terminated to library calls that require such termination.  If the tutorial violates these rules, dump it:)

Comment: @krystof - Yes.  Compare what you've written to the examples in "simple stream client" and "simple stream server".  While I still recommend beej's tutorial - I noticed that I fliped which code was client and server.  It does look like the API's are begin used correctly, however you are not checking return values.  Also make sure your server is started prior to running you client.  Finally for debugging, you may want to use 'netcat' to test you client separately from you server -- and the reverse.  Finally, make sure you can ping both computers to make sure you have connectivity

Answer (score 0):

`server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`
is wrong, you need to soecify the address of the server, either
by getting the address manually, hardcoded or by some discovery protocol
(lookup `gethostbyname()`